# How to check response of HTTP GET method using ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.GET_APP_MENU_LIST, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ComListMaster getCommonMasterByMasterId(@PathVariable("listid") Integer listId)
{
    ComListMaster commonMaster = commonService.getCommonMasterList(listId);
    logger.debug("Calling master list");
    return commonMaster;
}
```

Above code give me the exception:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{listid}"

Please tell me how to get GET response of above code.

Thanks in advance.
here is ComListMaster

```
public class ComListMaster extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable
```

{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5408136749548491686L;

```
@Id
@Column(name = "LIST_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer listId;

@Column(name = "LIST_DESC")
private String description;

@Column(name = "LIST_VALUE")
private String value;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "comListMaster")
private Set<ComListDetails> comListDetails = new HashSet<ComListDetails>();

public Integer getListId()
{
    return listId;
}

public void setListId(Integer listId)
{
    this.listId = listId;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description)
{
    this.description = description;
}

public String getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public Set<ComListDetails> getComListDetails()
{
    return comListDetails;
}

public void setComClientAddresses(Set<ComListDetails> comListDetails)
{
    this.comListDetails = comListDetails;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ComListMaster [listId=" + listId + ", description=" + description + ", value=" + value
            + ", comListDetails=" + comListDetails + "]";
}
```

}

My exception is: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{listid}"

API:    public static final String  GET_APP_MENU_LIST       = "/api/app/common/master/{listid}";

Comment: how do you call the method?

Comment: Is `listId` an integer (i-e a number) not a letter ?

Comment: seems like hes calling the url without changing the {listid} parameter hence the numberFormatExc. P.s. yep same thing as @Janar answered

Comment: @Zeromus How to overcome this Exception please tell me in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ("listid")-its not mandatory , then it wont java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{}".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{listId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ComListMaster getCommonMasterByMasterId(@PathVariable Integer listId)
{
    ComListMaster commonMaster = commonService.getCommonMasterList(listId);
    logger.debug("Calling master list");
    return commonMaster;
}
```

Comment: After removing ("listid") it gives me:  Missing URI template variable 'listId' for method parameter of type Integer. HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error. I want to trace record by using listid.

Comment: as @zeromus said the problem with your request. add your request into the question

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is correct.

The error seems to indicate you are trying to go to the `/api/app/common/master/{listid}` url. Instead you should substitute the {listid} with a real id, for example `/api/app/common/master/1`

Comment: Thanks a lot I got the output....wow. You saved my day. Thank you very much..Got what am expecting!!!!!!!

Comment: @AnupSonkusare you are welcome. if the answer was correct you should consider accepting it.

Comment: I accepted although my reputation below 15..Please up-vote my question